# Laravel 5 / Eloquent - Return a Date Based on the created_on Column Plus Variable Hours

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables: **statuses** and **status_logs**.

The **statuses** table has 3 columns: *id*, *name*, *duration*

The **status_logs** table has 3 columns: *id*, *status_id*, *created_at*

I have two models that look like this:

```
class Status extends Model{

    // Name of our database table
    protected $table = 'statuses';

    // Defines the relationship between this table and the status_logs table
    public function status_logs(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Status', 'status_id');

    }

}

class StatusLog extends Model{

    // Name of our database table
    protected $table = 'status_logs';

    // Defines the relationship between this table and the statuses table
    public function statuses(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Status', 'status_id');

    }

}
```

I can get data from both tables by using:

```
StatusLog::with('status')->get();
```

The result would look something like:

```
"status_logs": [{
    "id": 1,
    "status_id": 1,
    "created_at": "02:34:53 10/5/2017",
    "statuses": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "started"
        "duration": 48
    }
}]
```

I would like to add a column called *finish_at* to each object inside of the *status_logs* array.  This datetime will be the *created_at* value plus whatever the integer value of *duration* is.  *Duration* is the number of hours that we need to add to *created_at* to get the value of *finish_at*.

The result should look like:

```
"status_logs": [{
    "id": 1,
    "status_id": 1,
    "created_at": "02:34:53 10/5/2017",
    "finish_at": "02:34:53 10/7/2017",
    "statuses": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "started"
        "duration": 48
    }
}]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Eloquent appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) would solve this.

Add additional attribute and define the value. It would be look something like below.

```
class StatusLog extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['finish_at'];

    public function getFinishedAtAttribute()
    {
        // carbon to add hours
        $dt = Carbon::instance($this->attributes['created_at']);

        $dt->addHours($this->statuses->duration);

        return $dt->toDateTimeString(); // change to your desire format
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Carbon (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub), does something like this work for you:

```
$log->finished_at = $log->created_at->addHours($log->statuses()->duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is devide the duration in 24.
then add the devided duration in created_at value using using carbon 
like this one.

```
$log->finished_at = $log->created_at->addDays($log->statuses()->duration/24);
$log->save();
```